# Storing an array of time in VBA array

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

i want to store an array of time in VBA, like this but VBA rejects.

```
Dim timeA() As Variant
timeA = Array(01:42:32.75, 02:26:34.22, 05:03:23.54)
```

Instead I have to store it as serial instead like this.

```
Dim timeA() As Variant
timeA = Array(0.0712123842592593, 0.101784953703704, 0.21068912037037)
```

What can i do to store time in hh mm ss . msms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim timeA() As Variant
timeA = Array(#01:42:32#, #02:26:34#, #05:03:23#)
```

Unfortunately this won't work with fractions of seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try this, does it work?

```
Dim timeA() As Variant
timeA = Array("01:42:32.75", "02:26:34.22", "05:03:23.54")
```

Answer (score 0):

Timeserial will convert hours, minutes, and seconds into a Time, but it doesn't handle milliseconds.  If you don't need ms, you could use

```
Sub storetime()

    Dim vaTime As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    vaTime = Array(TimeSerial(1, 42, 32.75), TimeSerial(2, 26, 34.22), TimeSerial(5, 3, 23.54))

    For i = LBound(vaTime) To UBound(vaTime)
        Debug.Print Format(vaTime(i), "hh:mm:ss")
    Next i

End Sub
```

You might add ms like

```
vaTime = Array(TimeSerial(1, 42, 32) + (0.75 / 24 / 60 / 60), TimeSerial(2, 26, 34) + (0.22 / 24 / 60 / 60), TimeSerial(5, 3, 23) + (0.54 / 24 / 60 / 60))
```

Inspecting those values seems like it works, but I can't get the milliseconds to display, so I'm not sure what good it does you.

Comment: hmm.. that's an idea. but i'm looking for a quick method as my friend will need to key in the time manually.